# How To Install Phatch 16.1 Version on 16.04

Tags: apt

**The Problem**

I run Ubuntu 16.04. The latest Phatch version for 16.04 (0.2.7.1-3.1) stops loading at the splash screen. I have read that [version 0.2.7.1-4](http://thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/phatch) for 16.10 works fine and [should work on 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phatch/+bug/1567827/comments/13).

**The Question**

How can I install `0.2.7.1-4` on 16.04?

**What I've Tried**

- I've checked Ubuntu Software for other versions but apparently only
  the latest version of software per Ubuntu version is available.
- `sudo apt-get install phatch` (installs 0.2.7.1-3.1)
- `sudo apt-get install phatch=0.2.7.1-4` (says it's not found)

I tried applying the 16.04 patch [as recommended](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phatch/+bug/1567827/comments/17) but terminal just paused and seemingly did nothing until I killed it.

`sudo patch /usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/wxPil.py < phatch.diff`

If it's not possible to install the 16.10 version on 16.04 I will spend an hour and refresh myself on the ways to do stuff (apply it) manually.

Answer (score 1):

Patching works. I did it as [explained in ubuntuusers.de wiki](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntuusers.de%2FPhatch%2F%23Ubuntu-16-04&edit-text=&act=url), that is:

1. Save the patch file [phatch.diff](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phatch/+bug/1567827/+attachment/4654235/+files/phatch.diff) to your Downloads folder.
2. In a terminal:
   `sudo patch -b /usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/wxPil.py < ~/Downloads/phatch.diff`